# Can I bulk export aliases from pfSense (in order to import to another pfSense)?

Tags: pfsense

This seems like a simple thing but there doesn't appear to be an easy way (in the GUI). Before I dive into the file system level, I thought I'd ask --- is there an easy export of aliases from pfSense?

The online help (https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Aliases) lists a bulk import but makes no mention of export or bulk saving. I have a long list of aliases and it would be nice for this to be done swiftly and repeatably.

I have the High Availability pfsync set up but it does not seem to transfer any aliases even though "Firewall aliases" is checked.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:** So at least part of the syncing issue is that the two firewalls I am syncing are on different versions of pfSense... but my project is to move all the config options from one to the other so I can upgrade it.

Comment: Likely, you will first need to level the versions (change the target to the same version as the source). Next, you could simply capture the configuration in the CLI and paste it into the CLI on the target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to use `Diagnostics / Backup & Restore / Backup & Restore` to complete this task.

[image: Diagnostics / Backup & Restore / Backup & Restore]

Select "Aliases" under `Backup area` for both exporting and importing.

[image: Restore]

Obviously in the restore step you will need to upload the same file you downloaded in the backup step.

**Note: this did wipe out all previously existing aliases on the destination firewall.**